# Is the modal verb "can" transitive?

Tags: modal-verbs, transitivity

Are modal verbs, e.g. transitive or not?

Comment: Are you asking about ‘can’, as indicated by the title, or *all* modal verbs, as indicated by the text?

Comment: about can. But I'm not sure about all the others either.

Comment: No, only lexical verbs can be transitive.

Comment: @rhymer1987 Note that [*can*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can#h3) absolutely does have transitives senses. However, those senses are not modal. So, it's not clear if you are asking about the verb *in general* or, specifically, only its *modal* use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical definition of a transitive verb is "one that accepts one or more objects". *Can* and the other modal verbs do not accept objects. They are always followed by another verb (auxiliary be, have or main verb). So, *can* and the other verbs are not transitive.

Comment: You are talking about the *modal* senses of *can*. But the general verb certainly **does** have [transitive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can#h3) senses.